# UILabel adjusts to content size on IOS Simulator but not iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that will display cells which contain text of multiple lines. I have auto layout on and set up constraints for the leading space, trailing space, and top space. Shouldn't that be enough and auto layout takes care of the rest? The label expands to the text on the simulator but not my iPhone(I have the 5, ios7) My cell:

```
PFObject *temp = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (self.dataArray == self.postsArray) {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:10];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    label.text = [temp objectForKey:@"stringPost"];
    [button setTitle:[temp objectForKey:@"Event"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your simulator running iOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try taking away the trailing space constraint.  The leading and top constraint should be all that you need.